# Combining stat_bin with stat_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the following code to generate a histogram bar plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
dt <- data.frame(SurveyDate = sample(1:500, 1000, replace = TRUE))

ggplot(dt, aes(SurveyDate)) + stat_bin(bins = 50) + ylab('Survey Responses')
```

I would like to add a LOESS line on top of it, but this code:

```
ggplot(dt, aes(SurveyDate)) + stat_bin(bins = 50) + ylab('Survey Responses') +
  stat_smooth(aes(SurveyDate, ..count..), method='loess')
```

Gives me an error: `stat_smooth requires the following missing aesthetics: y`

How can I access the y value from stat_bin, from within stat_smooth?

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that there's a way to do it in a single command.  You could try this:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
dt <- data.frame(SurveyDate = sample(1:500, 1000, replace = TRUE))
p <- ggplot(dt, aes(SurveyDate)) + 
  stat_bin(bins = 50) +
  ylab('Survey Responses')
dat <- layer_data(p)
p +
  stat_smooth(data = dat, aes(x, y))
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Instead of writing `ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]] `, it would be better to write `layer_data(p)`. It's the officially supported API.

Comment: Thanks @ClausWilke for bringing this to my attention; I hadn't known about this function.