# Combining geom_line(stat='count') with geom_smooth() with a grouping variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add loess smoothing to my grouped line graph in ggplot that I have created using geom_line(stat='count').

This is a similar question, but the answer did not work with a grouping variable:
[Combining stat_bin with stat_smooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47911155/combining-stat-bin-with-stat-smooth)

```r
p = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, colour=factor(vs))) + 
  geom_line(stat = 'count') 

dat <- layer_data(p)
p + stat_smooth(data = dat, aes(x, y))
```

I want a smoothing line for each group. Using the above code I get the error: Error in factor(vs) : object 'vs' not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `stat_smooth` inherits unspecified aesthetics from the original plot, in this case `colour`. But `colour` refers to `vs`, which isn't a variable in the new `dat` data frame, hence the error. All you need to do though, is tell it what the new grouping variable is, in this case, `colour`. Note that I'm adding `method="lm", se=FALSE` as well because there's just not enough data points here for the default smooth.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, colour=factor(vs))) + 
  geom_line(stat = 'count') 
dat <- layer_data(p)
p + stat_smooth(data = dat, aes(x, y, colour=colour), 
                method="lm", se=FALSE)
```

[image]

You'll notice, though, that the colors don't match, because the variables don't match. I suspect the cleanest way to deal with this will be to get the counts ahead of time in a new data frame and then to use that in the plotting.

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% mutate_at(vars(cyl, vs), factor) %>%
  group_by(cyl, vs) %>% summarize(n=n()) %>%
ggplot() + aes(x=cyl, y=n, colour=vs, group=vs) +
  geom_line() +
  stat_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE)
```

[image]